# how to convert elapsed time from now to that date and pass that method to viewholder in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime-conversion

I am developing news app and I want to convert elapsed time from now to that date and pass that logic to viewholder in recyclerviewadapterclass correctly using kotlin

I am getting following time from server 
2019-10-08T15:16:05Z

and I want to achieve time like this below photo
[time image what I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRs59.png)

below my adapter class where I have implemented elapsed time from now to that date logic

```
class TopHeadlinesAdapter(val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TopHeadlinesAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    var articleList : List<Article> = listOf()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.news_list,parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return articleList.size
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.articleTitle.text = articleList.get(position).title
        holder.articleSourceName.text = articleList.get(position).source.name
        Picasso.get().load(articleList.get(position).urlToImage).into(holder.image)

        val input = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.US)
        val output = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US)
        var d = Date()
        try
        {
            d = input.parse(articleList.get(4).publishedAt)
        }
        catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        val formatted = output.format(d)
        val timelinePoint = LocalDateTime.parse(formatted)
        val now = LocalDateTime.now()

        var elapsedTime = Duration.between(timelinePoint, now)

        println(timelinePoint)
        println(now)
        elapsedTime.toMinutes()

        holder.articleTime.text =  elapsedTime
    }

    fun setMovieListItems(articleList: List<Article>){
        this.articleList = articleList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    fun example( ) {
    }
    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!) {

        val image: ImageView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        val articleTitle: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.articleTitle)
        val articleSourceName: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.articleSourceName)
        val imageCategory: ImageView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.imageCategory)
        val articleTime: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.articleTime)

    }
}
```

below Article.kt model class

```
data class Article(
    val author: String,
    val content: String,
    val description: String,
    val publishedAt: String,
    val source: Source,
    val title: String,
    val url: String,
    val urlToImage: String
)
```

Comment: thanks for edit suggestion @Enselic

Comment: You're welcome! And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @Enselic thank you so much for output I have tried by myself to solve problem but I did not get what I want I hope someone help me here

Comment: Basically, you can try `holder.articleTime.text =  "${elapsedTime.toMinutes()}m"`. if it's longer time, you can work around.

Comment: thank you so much but I am getting this exception java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-10-08T14:40:00Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[ChronoUnit][1]` class from [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to calculate the elapsed time in minutes:

If your server returns UTC datetime:

```
val elapsedMinutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(createdAt, LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC))
```